# Möbius maps preserve cross-ratios

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, mobius-transformation

> My question is different from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625578/invariance-of-cross-ratio-under-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-and-another-problem-relate) since my question asks to clarify the proof, while the other question asks to check if the proof is correct.

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3\in\mathbb{C}_\infty$ be distinct points. Then $\alpha(z):=[z; w_1, w_2, w_3]=[\mu(z); \mu(w_1), \mu(w_2), \mu(w_3)]=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}_\infty$ (where $\mu$ is a Möbius map). This means that Möbius maps preserve cross-ratios.

Here's the proof I have in the notes:

> $\mu^{-1}$ is a Möbius map, and:
>
> $$\alpha\circ \mu^{-1}(\mu(w_1))=\alpha(w_1)=0 $$
>   $$\alpha\circ \mu^{-1}(\mu(w_2))=\alpha(w_2)=1 $$
>   $$\alpha\circ \mu^{-1}(\mu(w_3))=\alpha(w_1)=\infty $$
>
> Thus $\alpha \circ \mu^{-1}(z)=[z;\mu(w_1), \mu(w_2), \mu(w_3)], \forall z\in \mathbb{C}_\infty$.

What I don't understand is how this proves that Möbius maps preserve cross-ratios. I would assume that we would have to take $\alpha(\mu(w))$ to show the preservation.

Moreover, if we show that some map is equal to $\alpha$ at just three points, how does this prove that two cross-ratios are equal? Perhaps I don't understand something about the meaning of cross-ratios.

Comment: Yes, I've read that. But no, it's not a duplicate, my question is asking to clarify the proof itself, not to help to prove the statement.

Comment: added an other proof to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625578/invariance-of-cross-ratio-under-m%c3%b6bius-transformation-and-another-problem-relate you can just calculate it out